# tkinter radio button list

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I am looking to dynamically add entries to a tkinter radio button list based on a configuration file.

The pertinent code is as follows:

```
    MODES = [
         ("Off", "0"),
         ("Wail", "W"),
    ]
    s_var = StringVar()
    s_var.set("0") # initialize
    x=0 #set column

    for text, mode in MODES:
         b = Radiobutton(bgridframe, text=text, height=g3_row, width=b_col,
                        bg="cyan", selectcolor="red", image=s_icon,
                        variable=s_var, value=mode, indicatoron=0,
                        compound=TOP,
                        )
        b.grid(row=6,column=x)
        x=x+3
```

I would like to add the following items to the loop based on a configuration setting : ("Yelp", "Y")  and ("Phaser", "P")  using an IF statement if possible.

Comment: OK, so what's the problem? Why don't you just do something like `if condition: MODES += [("Yelp", "Y"), ("Phaser", "P") ]`?

Comment: Thank you Johnathan, that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following lines of code before the "s_var=StringVar()" line.

```
    if m_yelp.get() == 1:
       MODES += [("Yelp", "Y")]
    if m_phaser.get() == 1:
       MODES +=[("Phaser", "P")]
```